# CSS3 Pie Failing Randomly over MAMP

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css, mamp, css3pie

I'm absolutely stumped on this, some local folder I'm working with - which was working fine this morning is now unable to render CSS3 pie (.htc) all of a sudden. I'm running a virtual local server through one computer on MAMP and accessing via another on the LAN, and I've never run into a problem with PIE before now.

The strange this is, I'll switch my MAMP local IP to that of another folder, and sometimes after a few goes, PIE will start working again. But as soon as I use the cursed folder, PIE just fails all over again and it's hard to get it back. Is there bad caching at work or something?

Any suggestions / steps would be super!

Comment: Have you tried the `.php` variant? http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type

Comment: Actually I think MAMP is screwing up, I've turned off the servers, but the webpage is still appearing in IE. And loading the IP up in Safari - gives me a completely mangled page, as though it's merged with the cached stuff from the other folder. Weird! Is there anyway to ensure no caching occurs with MAMP?